# Why return await Task.FromResult(true); instead of just return true?

Tags: c#, async-await

When you create a Xamarin Forms Master-Detail sample with VS2017 you get a MockDataStore class generated with methods such as

```
    public async Task<bool> DeleteItemAsync(string id)
    {
        var _item = items.Where((Item arg) => arg.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        items.Remove(_item);

        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

It feels naive to say *This is a Microsoft example therefore it must be right*.

I don't understand why those methods don't just `return true` and I've not seen this idiom explained. Is there something subtle I"m missing here, or is this a historic workaround that should have been cleaned up from the templates?

Comment: seens it is async it must follow TAP, so cant just return bool

Comment: It would make more sense to make the function not async, and `return Task.FromResult(true)`: has the same behaviour but doesn't need to build a state machine for this function.

Comment: @RenéVogt that's not true, you can `return true` even without any awaits in the body.

Comment: I can't mark things as correct if you write them as comments ;-)

Comment: Just a guess: Since people might use it as a template for their own expensive code. (Since it a Microsoft example.) They decided to make it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: When a function returns `Task` or `Task<T>` it will be handled asynchronously. But it itself doesn't need to be `async`.

Using `async`…`await` means the compiler builds a state machine to handle this. But if the only thing that you await is the last expression you can avoid this state machine:

```
public Task<bool> DeleteItemAsync(string id)
{
    // Nothing awaitable here...

    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

and create a function that runs synchronously – but has the signature and behaviour of an asynchronous function because of the call it makes to something that acts asynchronously.

Why return `Task<T>`: because that's what the caller is expecting: this cannot be changed without changing all callers, and their callers, and their callers, … all the way down (probably).

So the signature cannot be changed. You have to return something waitable. But you can just return the "waitability" of another result if that's the last thing you do (a bit like achieving tail-recursion).

> you get a MockDataStore

So this is only for testing: the overhead is unlikely to be significant and it gives code that can be adapted as a good example of what real code will look like. (Better than much – very poor – scaffolded code which provides a bad example.)

Note: with C#7 this would be a good case to make use of [`ValueTask<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types#generalized-async-return-types-and-valuetaskt) to avoid the overhead of allocating a `Task<T>` when the result is known immediately.

Comment: Why would a method "that runs synchronously" return a Task<T> and be named *Async in the first place?

Comment: `When a function returns Task or Task<T> it will be handled asynchronously.` And yet this very method is a method that returns a `Task` and is entirely synchronous, proving this statement false.

Comment: @mm8 You answered your own question in your answer, so why ask the question in a comment here?

Comment: @mm8: Clarified a function can be synchronous but expose asynchronous behaviour. (You also see this with iterators: outer function runs immediately to check parameters etc., inner function is the real iterator but to callers it is just an iterator.)

Comment: @Richard: Fair enough but exposing synchronous implementations as asynchronous methods is generally considered as bad practice. This could make sense if you are overriding a method with an asynchronous signature but apart from this the method is either asynchronous by nature or it's not.

Comment: @Richard Your iterator comparison doesn't really prove your point.  It, by design and even convention, it eagerly constructs the iterator and then defers actual iteration of it.  For an asynchronous method the design is similar, in that ti's supposed to synchronously *start* the asynchronous operation and then asynchronously do the long running work.

Comment: @mm8 True. One assumes this is a case where the real (ie. non-mock) method has a specific signature.

Comment: @Servy I've written a number of asynchronous methods that are not `async` for exactly this reason: only the final step is calling a function that is waitable. This is in production code where asynchronous behaviour is within a helper function. To put it another way: the net behaviour of calling the function is asynchronous; but not all functions that provide that behaviour will themselves be asynchronous.

Comment: @Richard Because the method isn't actually asynchronous, you can't actually say, "the net behaviour of calling the function is asynchronous" because it's not.  It's synchronous.  Now that's not to say that it's always *wrong* to have a synchronous `Task` returning method; there are indeed situations where it's okay.  You just can't call those synchronous methods "asynchronous", because they're *not*.

Comment: @Servy: This is a *mock* so needs to reflect the semantics and syntax of the method it is mocking. This appears to be a storage related method one would expected to be waitable; thus its mock needs to be as well.

Comment: @Richard This is a *placeholder* for demonstration purposes, not a mock.  The idea is that the developer is to look at the example and replace the `Task.FromResult` with real code.  But regardless, that's besides the point.  I'm not saying that the demo code shouldn't return a `Task`, I'm saying that you're wrong to say that this method is asynchronous.  It's not.  It's a *synchronous* method that acts *synchronously* and returns a `Task`.   Now that's not always a wrong thing to do, but it *is* wrong to say that such a method is asynchronous.  It's *not* asynchronous.

Comment: @Servy: From the outside (black box) it is acting asynchronously. The implementation is faking ("you get a MockDataStore class generated") that asynchronicity. Semantics are important and the overloading of terms here really doesn't help make this clear. To me an asynchronous function may return a result immediately, but its semantics – the caller may need to wait for the result – is the determining factor.

Comment: @Richard No, from the outside (black box) it's acting *synchronously*.  The function isn't returning until it has already completed, rather than returning a `Task` close to immediately and having that task complete at some point in the future.  Yes, semantics are indeed important, that's why it's important that you not say something behaves asynchronously when it behaves synchronously.  That's wrong.  While you personally may like calling synchronous methods "asynchronous", no one else does.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose the reasoning behind this was to prevent "async method lacks await operator" compiler warning. Authors of this autogenerated code wanted to mark function `async`, because that's what you will do anyway when you implement real functionality. So to prevent compiler warning (no autogenerated code should generate compiler warnings) you need to await something, and there is nothing to await in their code, so they've chosen to await `Task.FromResult`.

Of course when you write code yourself and not autogenerate it for future edits - you don't need to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I would have liked to see a comment warning that this is only for demo purposes because I've seen a few exanples of that code duplicated. I also found blog postings such as http://dhickey-ie-archive.azurewebsites.net/post/2013/04/11/An-async-await-antipattern-awaiting-tasks-instead-of-just-returning-them.aspx

Comment: @AndyDent well since that's a stub code, it's not necessary for it to be optimal (already fine if it compiles, bonus if it does something reasonable at runtime). And generating compiler warnings for autogenerated code is also not very good idea as for me. When you will implement real version of this code, you are not expected to do `await Task.FromResult` or similar anyway. All this is subjective though.

Comment: If you have guard logic that exits before making an async call, then that shortcut will need to  return await Task.FromResult(false); to avoid the warning.

Comment: @AndyDent not really, because warning happens only if you have no `await` operators at all in your method. If you have guard logic - you have `await` somewhere below and you will not need to do this, `return something` (or just `return` if your method returns `Task`) will do.

Answer (score 0):

This method might (should) as well be implemented synchronously as it is indeed truly synchronous:

```
public bool DeleteItem(string id)
{
    var _item = items.Where((Item arg) => arg.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    items.Remove(_item);

    return true;
}
```

It makes no sense for a synchronous method to be named *Async and return a `Task<T>`.

I guess you are supposed to add your own asynchronous removal logic in there. After all, the generated code is just sample code.

You would then await the actual database operation rather than `Task.FromResult`(true), i.e. you replace `Task.FromResult(true)` with an asynchronous call to a method that performs the database query and then returns `true` once the async method has returned successfully.

Comment: And all callers would need to also change. Including production code which is, presumably, a repository of some type making asynchronous calls (indirectly) to its physical storage. An interface – even if only implied – defines semantics and syntax.

Comment: @Richard: There is no interface mentioned in the question. Besides, you can't compare sample code that is generated from a template to production code.

Comment: not all interfaces are explicit, and note the name of the containing class.